# Running the impla query with -f give me error

Tags: impala

I am running below query by Impala shell:

```
/usr/bin/impala-shell --ssl -k --ca_cert /opt/cloudera/security/x509/chain.pem -i bdpdevmstla***t:25003 -f ./query_partition.hql 2>&1
```

The file which I am using has some commands like below:

```
alter table sit2_dp_gc_cnsm_anlt.csa_voic_call_opts_cnsr_smb set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
alter table sit2_dp_gc_cnsm_anlt.csa_voic_call_opts_cnsr_smb drop partition ( strt_date_part < '2021-01-15' );
```

But, I am getting below error:
Error, could not parse arguments "2>&1"

Can someone guide me what is wrong with mu query?

Comment: Why do you need to redirect the output? if you relly want to capture output pls use `<command> > output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: I am not sure what is 2>&1?

Comment: This is used to redirect ouput of your script to a file. Since you have not mentioned output file name, command is erring out. Please use this so as to capture the output correctly `/usr/bin/impala-shell --ssl -k --ca_cert /opt/cloudera/security/x509/chain.pem -i bdpdevmstla***t:25003 -f ./query_partition.hql >/tmp/output.txt 2>&1`